# Android NDK/JNI torch state control

Tags: camera, android-ndk, controls, torch

How can I change state of the camera flash throgh JNI function? I am looking to be able to have ON/OFF state control, just like in Java `CameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, state);` method. I've tried to search for it in native camera API ,but no success. Here's what I have done so far:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <android/native_window_jni.h>

#include <camera/NdkCameraDevice.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>

#include "messages-internal.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_android_rxjava_flashlightflicker_MainActivity_flasher(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    ACameraIdList *cameraIdList = NULL;
    const char *selectedCameraId = NULL;

    ACameraManager *cameraManager = ACameraManager_create();

    camera_status_t camera_status = ACAMERA_OK;
    camera_status = ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(cameraManager, &cameraIdList);

    /// Camera status not ok
    if (camera_status != ACAMERA_OK) {
        LOGE("Camera is bad id: %d \n", camera_status);
        return;
    }

    // There is no camera
    if (cameraIdList->numCameras < 1 ) {
        LOGE("Camera is not present on the device.");
        return;
    }

    selectedCameraId = cameraIdList->cameraIds[0];

    ACameraMetadata *cameraMetedata = NULL;

    ACameraManager_getCameraCharacteristics(cameraManager, selectedCameraId, &cameraMetedata);

   // ACaptureSessionOutput_create()

}
```

I also tried to look in asset manager but no success, can anybody experienced with NDK camera give me a hand with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This method is only available in Java API. You could access it through JNI, but IMO it would be easier and safer to write a wrapper static method in Java and have this wrapper called from your C++ code.

Comment: Of course, but my main objective here is to make it work at higher frequency than I am able to achieve with Java.

Comment: I am sorry. All methods that work with camera go through a few levels of indirection. There is no mechanism in Android to manipulate the torch at high frequency.

Comment: Alright, thank you for making it clearer. I thought I might be able to squeeze some extra speed doing it with NDK api. Is it related to HAL limitations of the device?